# adding a .ajax to my jquery causes page load to hang

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load

I have a page that uses bootstrap and jquery. Basically presents a table of conference attendees and allows the host the do a check-in. Host can also add a new attendee if they had not registered (ie not in DB).

I have an existing and working button called Attend which has an onclick event and calls a php function to update the DB. this works:

```
<script>
// This is the function that is called when the Arrive button is clicked
$(function() 
    {
        $('button#attendedButton').on('click', function (e) {
            var idFromRow = $(this).data('id');
            // Change the color of the button
            $(this).css('background-color', '#428bca')
            // Disable the button
            $(this).prop('disabled', true)
            // Change the button text
            $(this).text('Arrived')
            // Change the cell next this button and mark it as Atten
            $(this).closest('td').prev().text('Attended')
            idFromRow = idFromRow + '&action=setAttended'

            // for testing we can alert the variables 
            //alert(idFromRow)
            // Call the php function to update the database

            $.ajax({type: "GET", url:"CheckInFunctions.php", data: idFromRow})
            })
    }
)
</script>
```

Now I added a modal pop-up which asks for contact info and then onclick on that button has this function

```
<script>
// This is the function that is called when the Add button is clicked
$(function() 
    {
        $('button#addAttendeeSubmit').on('click', function (e) {

            fname = document.getElementById ("newAttendeefname").value
            lname = document.getElementById ("newAttendeelname").value
            email = document.getElementById ("newAttendeeemail").value
            note = document.getElementById ("newAttendeeNote").value
            phone = '111-555-1212'
            //phone = document.getElementById ("newAttendeefname").value

            newInfo = 'fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&note='+note+'&action=addAttendee'
            // for testing we can alert the variables 
            alert(newInfo)
            // console.log('here we are in add submit')
            // Call the php function to update the database
            //$.ajax({type: "GET", url:"CheckInFunctions.php", data: newInfo})
            })
    }
)
</script>
```

Strangely - Now when I load the page (even before any pop-up is presented) the page load hangs - if I comment out the .ajax call (as it is in the extract) the page loads, I can get the modal pop-up, fill in the info and see the alert.

What did i break ???

Comment: Have you tried using firebug (or some similar developer tool) to check, whether the GET-Request is sent and if so, what it returns?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that the actual server my ajax was talking to was intermittently down - therefore strange results. Sometimes the ajax call would succeed, sometimes it would hang or fail.